# Script tag attributes - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, client-side-templating

I am trying to understand the basics of templating and have the following problem. When I try to attach `ID` or/and `type` attribute to the `<script>` tag in my HTML code it just doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

           <head>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
             <script src="somescript.js"></script>

           </head>
           <body>

    <script type="text/html" id="template1">
                <form name="formXY">
                    <p>
                        <label>Field1
                            <input type="text" name="form_field1" value= "{{field1}}">
                        </label>
                        <button type="button">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran this in chrome/firefox/IE9/Opera and none of them parse the code between the `<script>` tags. Browsers think it is just a text field. When I remove `ID` and `type` attributes it is again parsed correctly.

I am probably missing something very basic...

Comment: And why would you place HTML in script tags ?

Comment: @adeneo - templates? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5679857/144496

Comment: @Martin - yes, some frameworks and templating systems do it that way, does'nt mean it's generally a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a non javascript `type` to the script tag, as the point is that you don't want the browser to parse it (as javascript), and by using a custom `type` the browser will ignore it (until you grab it with javascript that is)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <script src="somescript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template1">
        <form name="formXY">
        <p>
            <label>Field1
            <input type="text" name="form_field1" value= "{{field1}}">
            </label>
            <button type="button">Submit</button>
        </p>
        </form>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then in your javascript `somescript.js` you need to get the contents of that script tag using something like this

```
var uncompiledTemplate = document.getElementById('template1').innerHtml;

// then pass this template to your templating engine...
// if your using handlebars:
var template = Handlebars.compile(uncompiledTemplate);
```

And then you can work with your template!

Comment: Thanks, thats the thing I was missing:)...so first I need to install a templating engine and after that I can use the attributes. Thanks

Comment: The "text/html" type also protects the script contents from JavaScript (attempted) evaluation.  It doesn't have to be a totally made-up type.

Comment: @Pointy thanks! I'll update my answer. The custom type can be a good hint at what templating engine is in use perhaps? Some of the syntax can be similar

Comment: @PeteMitchell oh yes definitely, esp. if the template system has hooks in it to auto-compile such templates.

Comment: Using "text/html" is crucial for an IDE like PyCharm to format the content of the script tag correctly. If you use a made-up type it will interpret the content as an ordinary string, making usage of IDE features like highlighting etc useless...

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `<script>` tag is never parsed into DOM elements, the contents simply appear in the DOM as text (although `<script>` is `display:none;` by default so it does not appear on the page). If a `type` is provided has to be one that the browser recognises before it attempts to execute it. Note that older browsers used the `language` attribute instead.