# Html inside script tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to put things normally found in between the body tags in a script?

Like even an image:

```
<img src="url" alt="some_text">
```

Could I have that in `<script> <img src="url" alt="some_text"> </script>`

I want the user to be able to just copy something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

And it would include html code too, or even something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" src="htmlstuff"></script>
```

Comment: You are looking for a template system.

Comment: Why on earth would you need HTML markup inside of script tags?

Comment: Why are you trying to put html in the script tag?  If you want to generate new elements, you need to use the JavaScript functions like `document.createElement("div")`

Comment: [Check out this question!][1] Maybe you will find something useful...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679220/how-does-html-tags-work-inside-script-tag

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you just need to show html-tags on screen use html entities ie. &lt;script...&gt; http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: Maybe I'm reading too far into this, but are you possibly trying to find a way to include repeating chunks of HTML code (such as a header and footer) in your page without having to actually copy the code manually?

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442884/html-code-inside-script-tag) refer this SO question - "HTML code inside <Script> tag
"  this will help out in your query

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mix scripts and HTML (which I highly *don't* recommend) you can mix individual script blocks with that HTML. E.g.

```
<script> 
   //some JS code goes here
</script>

<img src="url" alt="some_text">
some more HTML goes here
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
some more HTML goes here

<script> 
   //some JS code goes here
</script>
```

But again - this is bad practice.

If you want your user grab link *just* to JS and have it produce HTML  - your JS code have to produce that HTML programmaticaly - look up [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement), [element.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) etc.

Note that if you can use jQuery - your life becomes a lot easier in both manually creating DOM elements as well as ability to load complete HTML e.g. using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.