# Using JavaScript Var as link for JS & HTML

Tags: javascript, html, var

I'm trying to use some variables as the link in both JavaScript and HTML but it is not working for either the **script src** portion or the **a href**. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>

// Please change these values

var Sermon_JWPlayer = "//content.jwplatform.com/players/l9aqB9m4-7l7ZMsAW.js" // JW Player Link
var Sermon_Address = "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/l9aqB9m4-EnqDUKfa.m4a" // Actual file url

// Should not need to modify below
var Share_Facebook = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + Sermon_Address
var Share_Twitter = "https://twitter.com/home?status=" + Sermon_Address
var Share_GooglePlus = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=" + Sermon_Address

<script src="" + Sermon_JWPlayer + ""></script>

<!-- Link Generator: http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com -->
<div align="right">

<!-- Download Link -->
<a href="' + Sermon_Address + '"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_download.png"></a> 

<!-- Facebook Share Link -->
<a href="' + Share_Facebook + '"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_facebook.png"></a> 

<!-- Twitter Share Link -->
<a href="' + Share_Twitter + '"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_twitter.png"></a> 

<!-- Google Plus Share Link -->
<a href="' + Share_GooglePlus + '"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_googleplus.png"></a> 

</div>
</script>
```

UPDATE
Thanks everyone for the input. I understand that I can't simply toss JS variables into HTML, I should just use JS entirely for having images with links. Here is how I resolved this:

```
<script>
// Only modify these two links

var sermon_JWPlayer = '//content.jwplatform.com/players/l9aqB9m4-7l7ZMsAW.js';
var sermon_directURL = 'http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/l9aqB9m4-EnqDUKfa.m4a';

// Should not need to modify below
var icon_download = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_download.png';
var icon_facebook = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_facebook.png';
var icon_twitter = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_twitter.png';
var icon_googleplus =     'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53823971/temp_images/icon_googleplus.png';

var Share_Facebook = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=';
var Share_FacebookFull = Share_Facebook.concat(sermon_JWPlayer);
var Share_Twitter = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=';
var Share_TwitterFull = Share_Twitter.concat(sermon_JWPlayer);
var Share_GooglePlus = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=';
var Share_GooglePlusFull = Share_GooglePlus.concat(sermon_JWPlayer);

var img = new Image();
img.src = "" + icon_download + "";
img.onclick = function() 
{window.location.href = sermon_directURL;};
document.body.appendChild(img);

var img = new Image();
img.src = "" + icon_facebook + "";
img.onclick = function() 
{window.location.href = Share_FacebookFull;};
document.body.appendChild(img);

var img = new Image();
img.src = "" + icon_twitter + "";
img.onclick = function() 
{window.location.href = Share_TwitterFull;};
document.body.appendChild(img);

var img = new Image();
img.src = "" + icon_googleplus + "";
img.onclick = function() 
{window.location.href = Share_GooglePlusFull;};
document.body.appendChild(img);

</script>
```

Comment: You can't simply stuff HTML in a script element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434196/html-inside-script-tags

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and HTML in very strange ways...

Comment: You should probably start by learning the basics: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills

Comment: You need to do something like `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('href', Sermon_JWPlayer);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById('myLink').href = Sermon_Address` inside your javascript code and give an id to your `<a>` element by using `id` attribute.

```
<a id='myLink'>
```