# Add class to element inside script/template

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following sample codes. I'm trying to add some class to the `id="section"` inside the javascript code but unsuccessful. Error: *Cannot read property 'classList' of null* when removing the commented codes. Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

Part 1:

```
var template = document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML;
var contents = '';
var section = document.createElement("div");

// These two lines cause the error
var section = document.getElementById("section");
section.classList.add("bg-yellow");

contents = template.replace(/\{\{title\}\}/, "Title");
section.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', contents);
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(section);
```

Part 2: (Updated from Randy Casburn's orig answer)

```js
var data = [{
"Title": "One"},
{"Title": "Two"},
{"Title": "Three"}];

var template = document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML;
var contents = '';
var section = document.createElement("div");

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 contents += template.replace(/\{\{title\}\}/, data[i].Title);
}

section.innerHTML = contents;
var innerSection = section.querySelector("#section");
innerSection.classList.add("bg-yellow","blue");

document.getElementById('content').appendChild(section);
```

```css
.sub-section{
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
}
.bg-yellow{
  background: yellow!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.blue{
  color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="template" id="container">
 <div id="section">
  <div class="sub-section">
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying the error occurs when you *uncomment* those lines?

Comment: @MTCoster yes, that's right

Comment: The browser ignores everything inside the `<script type="template" />` block. Thus you can not query it before adding it to the DOM properly. You read it, yet never add it to the DOM.

Comment: You cannot put html inside script tags

Comment: You can put whatever you want inside script tags, however the browser interpret it as plain text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679857/2831645

Comment: @Pete: You can actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script

Comment: `document.getElementById("section")` returns `null`, most likely because the template is not inserted yet into the DOM tree.

Comment: @Lain script type - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script: *Omitted or a JavaScript MIME type*:  Mime types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#JavaScript_types - I don't see any `type/template` mime type in that list of allowed types - perhaps the question you link to is out of date (was asked and answered in 2012)?  Also searching w3c, it lists no such thing

Comment: @Lain try validating that in the w3c validator you get: Error: Bad value template for attribute type on element script: Subtype missing.

From line 9, column 1; to line 9, column 39

>↩<body>↩↩<script type="template" id="container">↩ <div

Comment: @Pete: That does not make it not working Pete. I never said that it was valid HTML according to the w3c validator. I wrote that I can write whatever I feel like inside a script tag as long as it is not a permitted type. And, if you like it or not, it does work as you can see in various links on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple to accomplish. Create the `div` and set its `innerHTML` as the template contents. Then add the `div` to the DOM.

You were on the right track, but just skipped the one vital step.

```js
var data = [{
"Title": "One"},
{"Title": "Two"},
{"Title": "Three"}];

var template = document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML;
var contents = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 contents += template.replace(/\{\{title\}\}/, data[i].Title);
}

//var contents = template.replace(/\{\{title\}\}/, "Title");;
var section = document.createElement("div");
section.innerHTML = contents;
var innerSection = section.querySelectorAll(".section");
innerSection.forEach(el=>el.classList.add("bg-yellow"));
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(section);
```

```css
.sub-section {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="template" id="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="sub-section">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

EDIT: OP changed the use case in the question, so this updates the answer to reflect the new question :-/

Comment: You are now adding it twice. `section.innerHTML = template.replace(/\{\{title\}\}/, "Title");` and just add it once would be the way to go most likely.

Comment: @JavaScript - thanks that was an oversight. I'll correct.

Comment: @K.C. - The `classList.add()` method takes a comma separated list of class names to add all at once (if that's what you mean). See line 23 in the example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks. I'm wanting to challenge this solution when there is an array of data. The class seems to only apply to the first element. I'll update my codes above with the test data. Would u take a look at it, please?

Comment: @K.C. - You cannot do that with your current template because you set an `id` attribute in your template. While creating multiple elements from that template you will duplicate that `id` value which is not allowed (ids must be unique).

Comment: @K.C. - I modified my code to accommodate your new question. Note I changed the `id` to `class`, collected `All` of the nodes now, then iterated `forEach` and applied your class names. That should answer that query.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you for the suggestion. I'll modify my question to reflect both previous and new issues to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a content type other than Javascript in Script tags (or another scripting language that the browser understands), it will not be interpreted by the browser, and you can just access it as plain text.

refer( [How does HTML tags work inside script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679220/how-does-html-tags-work-inside-script-tag) )

you do not have the html DOM that you put in you script but you are trying to query on it.