# jquery selector does not work on element inside script tag using Cassette

Tags: jquery, cassette

When trying to access data-onload using `$("#index").data("onload")` I get back `'undefined'`:

```
<script type="text/html">
        <section id="index" data-onload="app.load()">
            <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
        </section>
</script>
```

Without the surrounding script tag everything works fine. This is loaded using [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) which wraps it inside script tags.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why should it be inside a `<script>` tag?

Comment: you are mixing HTML with Javascript

Comment: @gdoron it's loaded using cassette.net which wraps it inside script tags

Comment: Info on the `text/html` type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241387/html-script-tag-not-using-type-javascript-script-type-text-html

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler: Add all relevant details to your post beforehand next time, now you've got people trying to help you with the wrong problem because the question looks ridiculous without the necessary context.

Comment: Looks like this is an HTML template, a portion of a UI.  He's using a client-side JS framework, which should be referencing this template and rendering it into the DOM at some point.  So long as this template has not yet been rendered, the OP won't be able to manipulate the HTML.  Once this template is actually rendered into the page, however, the #index should match successfully.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler: Sorry for you, the more answers a post has the less attention it usually gets. Did you try adding **MORE JQUERY**?? Good luck ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contents of the script tag are not part of the DOM tree for your document.  If you think about it, this makes sense, since the JavaScript syntax is not valid HTML and you can just shove JavaScript in between the script tags.

Typically, you wouldn't put any HTML inside a script tag.  The presence of JavaScript in the data-onload attribute doesn't require the use of the script tag, so the simplest thing is probably to just erase the script tag.

On the other hand, if you're trying to use this chunk of HTML as a template, say for a client-side MVC framework.  That's the only time I've seen script type="text/html" that made sense.  In this case, you'll need to search for the #index section *after* the template has been rendered into the DOM.  Prior to that, this HTML doesn't really exist anywhere that you can access it with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Script elements that have an *unknown content-type* and it's going to be ignored.
 The browser does not know what to do with a text/html type script.

You just need:

```
    <section id="index" data-onload="YourTextValue">
        <div data-bind="YourTextValue"></div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the code inside the `<script>` - Tag is usually compiled as Javascript and is not part of the DOM. And I'm not sure if the `<script type="text/html">` is even a valid tag/attribute combination.

Remove the script tag, you don't need it.