# I cannot get the fields from my underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code, that dynamically append form field groups in a page using the `underscore` framework and I have a problem with getting the input fields of the template, so I don't know if I am doing something wrong that I cannot see.

The `underscore` template is like the following:

```
<script type="text/template" id="redirection_url_element">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="regular-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Enter the redirection URL', 'WPL' ); ?>" value="<%= (typeof( redirection_url ) !== 'undefined') ? redirection_url : '' %>" data-name="redirection_url" data-group="redirection" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="regular-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Weight', 'WPL' ); ?>" value="<%= (typeof( redirection_weight ) !== 'undefined') ? redirection_weight : '' %>" data-name="redirection_weight" data-group="redirection" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <i class="remove-parent-row">&times;</i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

So in my javascript code I do the following:

```
console.log ( $ ( '#redirection_url_element' ).find( ':input' ) );
```

and I get the following result:

```
prevObject: e.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#redirection_url_element :input"]
    context: document
    length: 0
    prevObject: e.fn.init[1]
    selector: "#redirection_url_element :input"
    __proto__: m[0]
```

and it seem that it cannot find the input fields. If you see the length is `0`.

Do you think I am doing something wrong ? Is there any error that I cannot see ?

**UPDATE #1**

The way I use the template is like following:

```
var $template_result = _.template ( $ ( '#redirection_url_element' ).html (), $data )
```

This is how I translate the template into HTML on the fly and I don't use the `backbone`. I just inject the `$template_result` into the destination element.

**UPDATE #2**

So, @Wolff, the table looks like that:

```
<table class="repeater_table">
    <tbody id="redirection_url_container">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" placeholder="Enter the redirection URL" value="" data-name="redirection_url" data-group="redirection">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" placeholder="Weight" value="" data-name="redirection_weight" data-group="redirection">
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class="remove-parent-row">×</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE #3**

Ok, I found the solution thanks to @Marcos Pérez Gude note and it is like following:

```
console.log ( $( $.parseHTML( $ ( '#redirection_url_element' ).text() ) ).find( ':input' ) );
```

I know it is somehow ugly, but it does the work for me. Do you think is there any better way to achive the above ?

Comment: Only as a note, in the template you should avoid the logic of the app. For example: `value="<%= (typeof( redirection_weight ) !== 'undefined') ? redirection_weight : '' %>" `. The ternary condition you can write in the Backbone View and pass the correct value to template, that you must to write `value="<%= redirection_weight%>"` and it can be empty with no problem.

Comment: The `<script>` element does not contain HTML. It contains text. jQuery's selectors don't work here.

Comment: So @Tomalak is there any alternative solution for this ?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude don't use `backbone`. I use `jQuery` and I translate the `underscore` on the fly.

Comment: @MerianosNikos You have to target in jQuery rendered HTML, so how it looks like?

Comment: @Wolff I have update my question, so do you think this answer your comment or you are asking for something different ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos I don't know this template BUT if you inspect your table in browser once it is rendered, how it looks like? This was my question. As a side note `@Wolff` doesn't send me message, `@A.Wolff` would

Comment: So what is your goal? In your third update, you aren't targeting elements in the DOM but in a jq variable used as wrapper. Now if your goal is to target elemnts in the DOM, looks obvious you weren't using relevant ID selector, should be: `$('#redirection_url_container').find(':input');`. If now your goal is to target elements before they are rendered, using `$.parseHTML( $ ( '#redirection_url_element' ).text() )` is a good solution, better than just using `$( $ ( '#redirection_url_element' ).text() )`

Comment: @Wolff this is what I need, to catch the input fields before they get injected into the HTML. Sorry if I confused you, but this is the target from the beggining.

Comment: @MerianosNikos So ya, i completly misunderstood question at the beginning. Now it makes sense :)

Comment: ;) Anyway thanks a lot for your assistace and the time you spend on my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't select things inside `<script>` tags because they aren't part of the DOM structure. [There's a thread about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575461/jquery-selector-does-not-work-on-element-inside-script-tag-using-cassette).

Did you try to run the selector against the destination element?

Sample:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#test').html('<span id="foo">Foo bar</span>');
  console.log($('#foo'));
});
</script>
```

Bear in mind browsers remove `tr` elements if they aren't inside `table` elements. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211708/jquery-is-unable-to-select-cells-outside-table).

Comment: The problem has been solved. If you see the third update of my question you can see the solution. Farthermore I think that maybe your answer is out of scope, so I don't downvote :) But keep in mind you may get downvoted by other members. Thanks a lot for your efort.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$( '#redirection_url_element' ).find( 'input' )
```

Comment: why downvote this? I think that is better this than `find(':input')`

Comment: It could be better regarding perf but doesn't explain OP's issue for sure. And maybe OP doesn't have just `<input/>` as form control and still wish to select all of them unregarding type. So in this case, [:input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) would be better

Comment: It's not me that downvoted you, but already I have try this and make no sence.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation @A.Wolff. Obviously, this is a low quality answer, but I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I did it and still didn't work. I found the solution and it is available on my third update of my question. Thanks for your efort.